# Семафоры и мультипоточность. Ошибка в sem_trywait()

Tags: c, многопоточность, unix

День добрый. 
Работаю с семаформами, по загадочным для меня причинам даже если сразу посли инициализации семафора пытаюсь им воспользоваться - не получается, sem_trywait возвращает -1.

```
for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
{
    sem_init(&utensils[i], 0, 1);
    sem_trywait(&utensils[i]); //returns -1 always! 

    //create new thread processes for the philosophers
    pthread_create(&phs[i], NULL, philosopher, &num[i]);
    //check if the threads are created
    assert(!(phs[i] == 0));

}
```

Comment: Я смотрю, вот эта дичь - `(void*) &philosopher`- продолжает кочевать из варианта в вариант.

Comment: таки работает. А как нужно?

Comment: Мало ли что "работает" или делает вид, что "работает"... Должно быть просто `philosopher` и все. С какой целью вы налепили туда это `(void *)`? Это не риторический вопрос. Чего именно вы пытались добиться этим `(void *)`? Какой логикой руководствовались?

Comment: Что у вас в `errno` после возврата `-1` из `sem_trywait`?

Comment: Так было сказано на паре. На самом деле, потому что функция сама по себе просто void и компайлер выдавал предупреждения - но сейчас поменяла на void* и все равно не работает.

Comment: "На паре" вам сказали чушь. "Компайлер выдавал предупреждения" и "все равно не работает" - это бесполезное словоблудие. Приводите конкретную информацию - объявления функций, сообщения компилятора.

Comment: errno равняется 9 после trywait. Сразу после инициализации - 78. 
При этом просто wait работает (тоже выдает -1, но в последствии получает семафор)
За указание на то, что (void*) не нужно использовать - спасибо.

Comment: На какой платформе вы работаете? Конкретные числа в `errno` бессмысленны без указания платформы. `78` на многих платформах - это `ENOSYS`, т.е. "функция не реализована", т.е. семафоры в данной реализации просто не поддерживаются вообще. Открывайте `<errno.h>` и смотрите, что такое `78` на вашей платформе.

Comment: Или вызовите `perror` после инициализации, чтобы напечатать содержательное сообщение об ошибке.

Comment: код в вопросе правильный.... стоит расширить его до полноценного минимального **компилируемого** примера...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак. 
Код правильный, ошибок с ним нет. 
Дело было в том, что я использую операционную систему Apple - в которой семафоры deprecated, поэтому инициализация не выполнялась. 
При использовании Linux - никаких проблем.